# .NET 4.5 for Windows Embedded POSReady 2009

Tags: windows, windows-xp, .net-framework, windows-xp-embedded, .net-4.5

**Is it possible to install .NET 4.5 on Windows Embedded POSReady 2009?**

Essentially I would like to run WPF 4.5 applications.

I cannot find anything online, but as far as I understand POSReady 2009 is similar to Windows XP SP3 which does not support .NET 4.5.

Comment: No; it's not supported but you can always try and install it.

Comment: What is the latest support .NET version?  3.5?

Comment: Yes; it's going to have the same limitations has XP

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No.
Windows Embedded 2009 is a SKU of Windows XP, which means .NET 4.5 and up is not supported. The last version you can install is [.NET 4.0.3](http://www.microsoft.com/en-pk/download/details.aspx?id=29053).

Answer (score 5):

According to the MSDN page [Microsoft .NET Framework Versions Supported by Windows Embedded Products](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/windows-embedded/archive/2015/08/10/microsoft-net-framework-versions-supported-by-windows-embedded-products.aspx), Windows Embedded POSReady 2009 supports .NET Framework versions 3.5 SP1 and 4.0, **but not v4.5 or higher**.